# Travelling to London, UK for a 3 day competition from India.

Tags: visas, london

Travelling to London, UK for a 3 day competition from India. I am staying in UK for 5 days. I Want to apply for a general visa of less than 6 months. **How much money should be in my bank account or in my parent's account**? and what documents are required?